Clustering based on exact number of items per group
I want each cluster to have 25 items, the final cluster which has the leftover points can have less than 25 items. I have tried the following (where 75,000 m is an arbitrarily large distance):
-- Truncate the clustered_results table to start fresh

DO $$ 
DECLARE
    area RECORD;  -- Declare a record to store the result of each loop iteration
    k int := 1;   -- Start with k = 1
    max_cluster_size int := 25;  -- Define the maximum cluster size
    large_clusters_count int;  -- Variable to hold the count of large clusters
BEGIN
    -- Outer loop: iterate through all "district_id" partitions
    FOR area IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT district_id 
        FROM pma_district_names 
        WHERE "campaignid" = -1 AND status = 'approved'
    ) LOOP
        
        -- Reset k for each new area
        k := 1;

        -- Inner loop: keep increasing k until all large clusters are processed
        LOOP
            -- Drop the temporary table if it exists
            DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temp_cluster_data;

            -- Create a temporary table to hold the clustering results
            CREATE TEMP TABLE temp_cluster_data AS
            SELECT "ID",
                   uuid,
                   district_id,
                   "centerPoint",
                   ST_ClusterKMeans(ST_Transform("centerPoint", 24313), k, 75000) 
                   OVER (ORDER BY "ID") AS nta_cluster_id
            FROM pma_district_names pma
            WHERE pma.district_id = area.district_id
              AND pma."campaignid" = -1
              AND pma.status = 'approved'
             and pma.uuid not in (select nta_id from clustered_results);

            -- Insert clusters with size less than or equal to 25 items into the results table
            
             INSERT INTO clustered_results (cluster_id, nta_id, coordinates)
            SELECT district_id || '_' || nta_cluster_id::text|| '_' ||k AS cluster_id, 
                   uuid::text AS nta_id, 
                   "centerPoint" AS lat_long
            FROM temp_cluster_data
            WHERE nta_cluster_id IS NOT NULL 
              AND nta_cluster_id in 
             (select nta_cluster_id from (select nta_cluster_id,count(*) from temp_cluster_data
             group by 1
             having count(*)<=max_cluster_size
             )a);

            -- Count how many clusters are larger than 25
            SELECT COUNT(*) INTO large_clusters_count
            FROM (
                SELECT nta_cluster_id, COUNT(*) AS cluster_count
                FROM temp_cluster_data
                GROUP BY nta_cluster_id
                HAVING COUNT(*) > max_cluster_size
            ) AS large_clusters;

            -- If there are no large clusters, exit the inner loop for this area
            IF large_clusters_count = 0 THEN
                EXIT;  -- No large clusters, exit the inner loop for this area
            END IF;

            -- Otherwise, increase k and continue iterating on the larger clusters
            k := k + 1;

        END LOOP;

    END LOOP;  END $$;

But the average number of items per cluster is around 11, i.e. the number per cluster is quite variable.

Except in certain specific cases, it is not possible to group a fixed number of points (e.g., 25) into clusters and adhere to the clustering rules of the k-means algorithm simultaneously ! So what are you trying to do ? Please give an example. You could use the constrained k-means algorithm or the the balanced k-means algorithm but both algorithm are compute-intensive (especially the constrained k-means) and both won't respect the rule of minimum distance to the centroid.
